# How to get a var from a foreach loop outside the foreach?

Tags: c#, sql

I wrote a foreach loop in c# and in the loop is a var with a sql query.

Here is the foreach code:

```
foreach (performance pp in thestm)
{
      var sql = from p in db.performances
               where pp.end_time > strSt && pp.end_time < strEt && pp.stage_id == selStage
               select p;
}
```

Now i would like something to do like:

```
if (sql.Any())
{
    MessageBox.Show("Time is not available");
}
else
{
    // Other code
}
```

But I can't get the var sql.

So there is an error in the if(sql.Any())

So how can I get this var sql?

Comment: Which `sql` do you want? You are creating one per loop iteration...

Comment: Once you exit the `foreach` loop your `var sql` goes out of scope. You could put your code after you set the var and before the loop ends though

Comment: You could create a variable before the `foreach` loop, and set the variable equal to `var sql` in the loop, but this will only capture the last iteration of the loop.

Comment: What happens if the loop never executes because the sequence is empty?

Comment: Also, note that the semantics of a query which closes over a foreach loop variable is different between C# 4 and C# 5, which can be surprising.

Comment: I wrote a foreach. In that foreach I go through all table records to check if the chosen time is available. Like for a reservation. But I just want at the end (when all the records are done) see the result of there were any records true. So not for every record, So I can give one message and not for every record.

Comment: in that case, you could use a bool, declare the bool before the loop as false, and in the loop set it to true if `sql.any()` is ever true

Comment: It is strange that you would want to continue the loop after one of the queries returns anything.

Comment: it's like a reservation page for an admin. And when I want to book a reservation for a time that is already reserved, I want to have a message. So I loop through all reservations and check if the chosen time is already reserved. But when I place the sql.any in my foreach loop it will give by every record that is true a message. But I only want one message.

Comment: See the marked duplicates for the answer to your literal question. But, take heed of the comments above, as they call out several potential design issues with your code. It is not clear at all that using the most recent value of `sql` outside the loop is useful, or even what you really wanted to do.

Comment: `bool hasConflict = false;
    foreach (performance pp in thestm)
    {
          var sql = from p in db.performances
               where pp.end_time > strSt && pp.end_time < strEt && 
               pp.stage_id == selStage
               select p;
          if(sql.Any()) 
              {
                  hasConflict = true;
                  break;  
              }
    }`

Comment: `if (hasConflict)
    {
    MessageBox.Show("Time is not available");
    }`

Comment: That sounds good. I can't try it anymore today. So I will test it tomorrow.  I hope it will work

Comment: It's unclear why you need a `foreach`. Why not `thestm.Any(pp => …)`?

Comment: I tried your solution @hellyale and it worked. Thank you very much !

Comment: I said that in my post and got downvoted.

Answer (score 0):

You have to place variable outside the loop, conditional check inside the loop, or abstract.  The abstraction would be better suited to your needs, you execute a database queries, to populate a collection, then appear to be checking for a result.

If I misunderstood, I apologize.

```
public class DbContext
{
     public IEnumerable<Sample> GetAllSamples(string query)
     {
          // Do your query, return your Sample object.
     }
}
```

So, if your calling the for that data, inside another class.

```
var context = new DbContext();
var samples = context.GetAllSamples("....");
if(samples.Any())
{
    // Do Something
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
    private static void Main(string[] args) {
        Test1();
    }
    #region Test1

    private static void Test1() {
        var performances = new List<Performance>();
        var thestm = new List<Performance>();

        var perf1 = new Performance {
            StartTime = 2,
            EndTime = 10,
            Stage = 4
        };
        var perf2 = new Performance {
            StartTime = 1,
            EndTime = 5,
            Stage = 4
        };
        var perf3 = new Performance {
            StartTime = 4,
            EndTime = 6,
            Stage = 4
        };
        var perf4 = new Performance {
            StartTime = 1,
            EndTime = 9,
            Stage = 4
        };


        performances.Add(perf2);
        performances.Add(perf1);

        thestm.Add(perf3);
        thestm.Add(perf4);

        var timeIsNotAvailable = false;
        string messageBoxString = "This time is available!";

        foreach (var pp in thestm) {
            timeIsNotAvailable = performances.Any(perf => perf.EndTime > pp.EndTime && perf.StartTime < pp.StartTime &&
                                                        perf.Stage == pp.Stage);
            if (timeIsNotAvailable) {
                messageBoxString = "This time is not available";
                break;
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine(messageBoxString);

        var stop = "i";
    }
}

internal class Performance {
    public int Stage { get; set; }

    public int StartTime { get; set; }

    public int EndTime { get; set; }
}

#endregion
```

My lists are representing your two values, the times that you are comparing and the times that you are comparing against. If this does not solve it for you, let me know what i am not accounting for and i will update accordingly.